# Is there a Windows 32 bit equivalent of sound.drv (16 bit sound driver)

Tags: vb6

I'm working with a very old program that uses sound.drv to make some simple sounds (like the old Quickbasic sound driver, or the even more ancient Commodore64 synthesizer)

Anyway... I"m trying to find out if there is a 32 bit equivalent library.  Googled on it, but no joy.

Here's an example of the of the declarations

```
Declare Function OpenSound Lib "sound.drv" () As Integer
```

You use Sound.drv to make tones and such, not to play actual sound files.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic win32 sound function is [PlaySound()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712879.aspx).  May be a good place to start.  What format are the sounds are you playing?